# Why does Eclipse sometimes rebuild the whole workspace?

Tags: java, eclipse

I use Eclipse Luna 4.4.0. After I start Eclipse and haven't changed anything it sometimes rebuilds the whole workspace which is sort of annoying. It is not an incremental build, but a full rebuild (which includes cleaning output folders of all projects).

I use autobuild for projects (all java, using svn and git), but autobuild should not lead to this behaviour.

What triggers the complete workspace rebuild? The error log does not contain any hint.

Comment: This seems to be still happening in 2020. Maybe it has something to do with m2e (Maven integration) - sometimes editing one pom.xml triggers the rebuild of all the projects in workspace...

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the builder gets triggered as follows (from [the Eclipse wiki](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_turn_off_autobuilding_of_Java_code%3F)).

> JDT uses the autobuild facilities provided by the platform. If a resource changes, the platform checks the project description file (see .project in your projects). When the file contains a reference to the Java builder, the builder gets notified of the change and will then compile the Java source file and its dependents.

I don't know what exactly triggers the build on startup (I've always had the *feeling* that it somewhow "made sense" for Eclipse to do so when starting). Could it be that some of your resources are `touch`ed (if you're on a Linux system) during startup?

It also says there on the wiki how to switch off autobuilding (which I guess you're already fully aware of):

> autobuild can be turned off through **Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Build automatically**.

There are also related bugs on Eclipse's bugzilla, e.g. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=73969, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=172444.

Comment: it makes sense that Eclipse builds anything that was touched since last build. But I did definitely not touch anything and still eclipse occasionally rebuilds every project including a clean.

Comment: thanks for the link to Eclipse bugzilla: The thread is from 2005 but lot of indications that internal workings/bug of Eclipse could trigger an unneeded full rebuild.

Comment: @wero: I've found the link an interesting read myself, despite its age.